# getting signature error for _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sapui5, amazon-mws

I'm trying to post fulfillment data on SubmitFeed using javascript in sapui5 and i have done the steps as,

1) I have created json object for fulfillment data and converted it into XML again XML converted into MD5.
JSON code:-

```
{
                      "AmazonEnvelope": {
                            "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                            "-xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "amznenvelope.xsd",
                            "Header": {
                              "DocumentVersion": "1.01",
                              "MerchantIdentifier": "Example"
                            },
                            "MessageType": "OrderFulfillment",
                            "Message": {
                              "MessageID": "1",
                              "OperationType": "Update",
                              "OrderFulfillment": {
                                "AmazonOrderID": "102-8289425-201934",
                                "FulfillmentDate": "2017-06-20T00:36:33-08:00",
                                "FulfillmentData": {
                                  "CarrierName": "UPS",
                                  "ShippingMethod": "Second Day",
                                  "ShipperTrackingNumber": "1234567890"
                                },
                                "Item": {
                                  "AmazonOrderItemCode": "1234567",
                                  "MerchantFulfillmentItemID": "1234567",
                                  "Quantity": "2"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        };
```

2) Created signature as per the api documents.
3) Post the data on Feed/2009-01-01.

but i'm getting the error as:-

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidAddress</Code>
    <Message>Resource /$metadata is not found on this server. API Version is missing</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestID>c00cb653-f53c-445f-9f24-82587144805d</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
"
```

Please help me to resolve this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is `InvalidAddress`, not a signature check error. It seems whatever you are doing in step 3 (Post the data on Feed/2009-01-01) does not work as expected. The MWS servers see a request for `/$metadata` instead of API name and version. Your question does not include the piece of code that does that.